# How Find Intent video link in android

Tags: html

how to find intent video id link for external video player

```html
<div class="box-container" style="align-items: center; font-family: sans-serif; height: auto; justify-content: center; margin: 0px auto; position: relative;">
  <div style="align-items: center; background-color: #cccccc; display: flex; float: left; height: 100px; justify-content: center; margin: 3.76705px; position: relative; width: 116.898px;">
    <a href="intent://=#Intent;scheme=xmtv;package=co.wuffy.player;end"><img height="120" src=" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your img src is not valid

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

I had to add a `"` to your img src

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".box-container div a").href)

// OR

console.log(document.querySelector("a[href^=intent]").href)
```

```html
<div class="box-container" style="align-items: center; font-family: sans-serif; height: auto; justify-content: center; margin: 0px auto; position: relative;">
  <div style="align-items: center; background-color: #cccccc; display: flex; float: left; height: 100px; justify-content: center; margin: 3.76705px; position: relative; width: 116.898px;">
    <a href="intent://=#Intent;scheme=xmtv;package=co.wuffy.player;end"><img height="120" src="" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: İ wanna find videos id for intent link how to find